# Запрос на исправление неполадок в базе данных

Tags: 1с

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой запрос нужно отправить, чтобы все неполадки в базе данных исправлялись. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Неполадки в базе данных - это по большей части ошибки пользователей, например, пользователь мог пометить на удаление контрагента, а тот, в свою очередь использовался в какой-либо операции, администртор не проверил это и удалил его, итог - ошибка. В таком контексте можно написать обработку которая найдет все пустые ссылки и заменит/предложит пользователю их заменить на какое-либо значение. (замечу, что запрос только читает данные, но не получает их)

Если речь идет о конфигурации, вы можете запустьть анализ ошибок Конфигурация->Проверка конфигурации